# Source Tree and Github not seeing all of my files

Tags: git, version-control, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I tried creating a repository of all the files I am using in this project.

And for some reason when I added files to my local directory, only some of them were picked up by SourceTree and commited and pushed to Github.

Here is what the local directory looks like (Each folder contains files):

[image]

The folders boxed in red are not being seen at all by SourceTree.

Here is what displayed in SourceTree:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, Only the Vb.net project and the javascript project were picked up by SoruceTree. What do I need to do to pickup those other folders of files?

Comment: I can barely see what you mean... Can you list files that are existent but not tracked by Git? Also can you show the contents of your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: where is the .gitignore file by default?

Comment: In your repository's root directory.

Comment: I see nothing labeled `.gitignore` in the .git folder at the root or anywhere else in the directory

Comment: OK, and what about the files? Those two screenshots do not show enough information to make an educated guess.

Comment: what are you refering to when you say "the files"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37392/discussion-between-jth41-and-nils-werner)

Comment: by default git will not stage sub-folder contents. you can run

Answer (score 13):

I met the same problem, and after trying @khanmizan's method(which didn't work in my case) and searching more in the internet, I got the solution:
in stead of using

```
git add .
```

I used

```
git add . -f
```

The original answer is here: [commit a file in bin directory](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/150610/commit-a-file-in-bin-directory)

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment or edit on khanmizan's answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on others' answer/question. And I don't feel confident enough to edit others' answer.. But thanks EWit, I will note it next time. :)

Answer (score 4):

By default git will not stage sub-folder contents. you can run the following command from the root directory of your repo to stage all files.

```
git add .
```

Now all files should be displayed in source tree. However if you still find some file missing, please check the .gitignore file. by default .gitignore file blacklists all generated files like .exe .jar etc.